# Oracle SQL: Dividing Counts into unique and non unique columns

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, window-functions

I have a table that looks like this:

```
|FileID|  File Info   |
| ---- | ------------ |
|   1  | X            |
|   1  | Y            |
|   2  | Y            |
|   2  | Z            |
|   2  | A            |
```

I want to aggregate by FileID and split the File Info column into 2 separate  count columns. I want 1 column to have the count of the Unique File Info and the other to be a count of non-Unique file info.

The result would ideally look like this:

```
|FileID| Count(Unique)| Count(Non-unique) |
| ---- | ------------ | ----------------- |
|   1  | 1            | 1                 |
|   2  | 2            | 1                 |
```

where the non-unique count is the 'Y' and the unique count is from the 'X' and 'Z, A' for FileID 1 and 2 respectively.

I'm looking for ways to gauge uniqueness between files rather than within.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How many different `FileID` values do you expect to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function in every row to check if `FileInfo` is unique and then use conditional aggregation to get the results that you want:

```
SELECT FileID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN counter = 1 THEN 1 END) count_unique,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN counter > 1 THEN 1 END) count_non_unique
FROM (
  SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.FileInfo) counter
  FROM tablename t
) t
GROUP BY FileID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cf081c794eb998dc0674678780048444).

Answer (score 1):

First you select the "Non Unique" rows from the table

```
SELECT FileInfo
FROM sometableyoudidnotname
GROUP BY FileInfo
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now that you know which ones are unique and non unique you can left join to that table to get the "status" and count it up.

```
SELECT base.FileID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN u.FileID is NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nonunique,
       SUM(CASE WHEN u.FileID is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unique
FROM sometableyoudidnotname base
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT FileInfo
  FROM sometableyoudidnotname
  GROUP BY FileInfo
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) u ON base.FileInfo = u.FileInfo
GROUP BY base.FileID
```

Comment: I don't know the Oracle optimizer, but this is perhaps a bit faster than my query,

Comment: @jarlh -- yeah I was thinking that too -- but I think yours is clearer -- esp if there are other categories (count of items which appear 3 times etc)

Answer (score 0):

Have a derived table that counts occurrences of each fileid. `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select t1.FileID,
       sum(case when t2.ficount = 1 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when t2.ficount > 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from tablename t1
join
(
    select fileinfo, count(*) ficount
    from tablename
    group by fileinfo
) t2
on t1.fileinfo = t2.fileinfo
group by t1.FileID
```